# CNN model progression

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

My project revolves around classifying butterflies into 23 labels.
I've done abit of code and i am stuck on how to make the model for it.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

print("Loading Images")
df=pd.read_csv("../input/mydata/data/train.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
columns = [
"Label"
]
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255.,
)
traindata = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=df,
directory="../input/mydata/data/train",
x_col="Filename",
y_col=columns,
color_mode='rgb',
batch_size=16,
class_mode="raw",
target_size=(600,400),
shuffle=True,
 
)
```

This is what i've done and it outputs I have 10270 validated image file names
How do i progress from there to make a sequential model

Comment: Follow and understand the tutorials - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Comment: This is not the purpose of stackoverflow, but you can still. You should ask a precise question. Please also read the guidelines for asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tqdm import tqdm

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

basedir = 'archive/raw-img/'
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    basedir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    )

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    basedir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    )

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([  # layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
                               # layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0 / 255,
            input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation='softmax'),
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=2,
          batch_size=batch_size)

(loss, acc) = model.evaluate(val_ds)
print ('Accuracy', acc)
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, can i contact you via email or discord, it regarding my own cnn and wanted to ask for help

Comment: Upload your code into github, in going to help you there

Comment: whats your github